# Custom Share using Javascript not working as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, share

I am working on a simple custom share where user will click on the share button which will show list of share option and then user can click on any one of them to share the page.

I have setup code on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVbRYa) not sure why it is not working.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="share-btn" href="#">S</a>
  <div class="share"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com"> F</a>
  </div>

  <div class="share"><a  href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">W</a></div>

  <div class="share"><a  href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=This is the Title+http://domain.com/article/this-is-article
">T</a></div>


</body>

</html>


   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.share').click(function() {
       var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
       if (window.focus) {
         NWin.focus();
       }
       return false;
     });
   });

   $(".share-btn").click(function() {
     $(".share").toggle();
   });
```

Comment: Well probably because the $(this) is the div which has no property called href.

Comment: @lain, You have a point

Comment: @lain, You r right i changed it to `this` to  `'.share > a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $('.share').click to $('.share > a').click else the $(this) refers to the div which has no property called href.

Here is an example for it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWObQo

```
$('.share > a').click(function() {
```

Comment: I have to add ID or class to anchor otherwise it will show facebook for all share.

Comment: What do you mean? Works fine on your codepen by just changing the selector.

Comment: I added class to each anchor and trigger event on `sharethis` ` $('.sharethis').click(function() {`

Comment: Well you are free to do so, yet I can not see the actual change by that. It is still going to select the same three anchor tags, is it not?

Comment: You approach is also correct i miss understood & change the `this` inside this function not on click event.I will mark you answer correct as it solve the problem. But i tool a different approach .

Comment: Well to be fair, for what you are trying to do you can either totally remove the div tag or the anchor tag. I would stay with the anchor tag since it is tabable by default tho.

Comment: agree with you this is just for testing HTML can be refined as you said. Thanks